# How to change a type's accessor with Mono.Cecil

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, mono.cecil, class-visibility

Is this possible?

I want to make a public class internal.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Possible ? Of course! It can be as simple as:

1) load the assembly;

2) find the type;

3) change it's visibility;

4) save the assembly

However you can end up with a very broken assembly. E.g. if the type `T` is now internal but is used in public fields, properties, methods... then **peverify** won't like it.

For the (open source) [Moonlight](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/) project we used a Cecil-based tuner which removed and (in your case) **internalized** a lot of stuff so that Mono BCL (matching the MS full framework) could look like the Silverlight BCL.

I guess you to read the (MIT.X11 licensed) source code from the link below to get a **fully** working implementation of internalizing a type.

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/tuner

https://github.com/mono/moon/tree/master/class/tuning

**EDIT** mode details (copy/pasted/adapted) from [MoonlightA11yProcessor.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/tuner/Mono.Tuner/MoonlightA11yProcessor.cs)

```
    void MakeApiInternal ()
    {
        foreach (TypeDefinition type in _assembly.MainModule.Types) {
            if (type.IsPublic)
                type.IsPublic = false;

            if (type.HasMethods)
                foreach (MethodDefinition method in type.Methods.Where (m => !m.IsConstructor))
                    if (method.IsPublic)
                        method.IsAssembly = true;
        }
    }
```

That will make every **public** type in (already loaded) `_assembly` an `internal` type (including all non-constuctor methods). You just need to **filter** your own type (e.g. based on it's `FullName` property) and save it back.

Comment: thanks, but i was looking for the syntax to change it's visibility

Comment: I know this answer is a bit old, but can't you just do `_assembly.MainModule.GetType("fullTypeName")`?

Comment: @ArkaMajumdar You can, but in the example he show how to do it for all methods in all types